# Load user settings with Laravel 5.6

Tags: php, laravel

I'd like to be able to modify the Auth->user() data that Laravel 5.6 uses.  I have table called settings with a column called `user_id` in it that corresponds to a user id.

I tried modifying `app\User.php` and adding a `__construct` function:

```
   public function __construct() {

        $this->settings = Settings::where('user_id',
                Auth->user->id()
                )->first();
    }
```

And I created a file `app\Settings.php` with the following:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class settings extends Model
{
    protected $table = "settings";

}
```

However I'm getting a user error on the `Auth->user()->id` line in `User.php`, although I'm sure thats the correct way to reference it?

How can I load the data from the `settings` table to the User class?

Answer (score 5):

You can just use `load()` method to lazy load the relation:

```
auth()->user()->load('settings');
```

You need to do this just once per request, in a middleware for example. Then you'll be able to use the data in any part of your app:

```
{{ auth()->user()->settings->theme }}
```

Of course, to make this work you need to define relationship in the `User` model, for example:

```
public function settings()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Settings::class);
}
```

Comment: Alexey again! You are my Laravel spirit guide.  Where abouts can I place the code to do this?

Comment: @Chud37 you could put it in a [middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/middleware) and apply the middleware to the routes where you want to use the data (or even to all routes).

Comment: Hmm, I'm getting `Call to a member function load() on null`.  I created a middleware, and added it to Kernal.php's `protected $middleware` array.  Then in the `function handle()` I've got your `load('settings')` line, but its giving me that errror.

Comment: @Chud37 you need to make sure the `StartSession` middleware was executed before you're trying to execute your middleware.