# Load user settings from table

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.6

In Laravel 5.6, I have a settings table with a `user_id`.

I am trying to be able to link the `\App\User` class with the settings table.

I've got a `Settings` model with the following:

```
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class settings extends Model
{
    protected $table = "settings";
}
```

And in my `\App\User.php` file I've got the following function:

```
public function settings() {
    $this->belongsTo(Settings::class);  
}
```

and at the top of that file i've got `Uses App\Settings`.

However when I run the following code in my master.blade.php template:

`{{ dd(auth()->user()->settings()) }}`

I just get `null`.  Why is this?

Comment: Did you try loading this way? `auth()->user()->with('settings')`?

Comment: @Ru where do I do that, in the User class?

Comment: No, from the controller.

Comment: I dont have a user controller in `app\http\controllers\auth` :(

Comment: You're using the wrong relationship. I've [shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48975174/1227923) the correct one. Since `user_id` in in the `settings` table, then you should use the `hasOne` relationship. `User `has one `Settings`. Also, when you're using `settings()` the query will not be executed. Use `->settings` as I've shown in that old answer.

Comment: Mind your casing. Your class is named lowercase `settings`, instead of `Settings`, which you are trying to refer to.

Comment: This happened lot many times with me. Maybe you forgot to `return` the `$this->belongsTo(...)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in Your User Model :

```
public function settings() {
   return $this->belongsTo('App\Settings');  
}
```

In Your Blade :

```
 {{ Auth::user()->settings }}
```

Comment: Hello, I've changed my relationship to `$this->hasOne(Settings::class);` in user class, and in blade i've got `{{ dd(Auth::user()->settings) }`.  I get the error `App\User::settings must return a relationship instance. `

Comment: I wasn't `returning` it! I added the return into the function and it worked.  Thank you!

Comment: This cannot possibly work for you since you have `user_id` in the `settings` table. This will only work if you have `settings_id` in the `users` table.

Answer (score 0):

Try below Code :

Your Setting.php Model:

```
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class Setting extends Model
{
    protected $fillable =['your_field1_name','your_field2_name','your_field_ect_name'];
    public function users() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\User');
    }
}
```

Your User.php Model :

```
<?php

namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class User extends Model
{
    protected $fillable =['your_field1_name','your_field2_name','your_field_ect_name'];
    public function settings() {
        $this->belongsTo('App\Setting');  
    }
}
```

**Note:Your model name must be singular**

$fillable : Protect against mass-assignment. A mass-assignment vulnerability occurs when a user passes an unexpected HTTP parameter through a request, and that parameter changes a column in your database you did not expect.

For more info visit :https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent#eloquent-model-conventions